# Merging multiple worksheets with Images into one workbook - Image error

Tags: vba, excel

I just started using VBA and I've been using a code to merge multiple worksheets into a single workbook, it works fine except for worksheets containing images. In these cases the image won't show in the new workbook created. It appears the box where the image should be with an error message. I use MS Office 2010.

Here follows the code I've been using:

```
Sub MergePlans()
Dim CurFile As String, DirLoc As String
Dim DestWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Object

DirLoc = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Merge\" 
CurFile = Dir(DirLoc & "*.xlsx")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set DestWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet)

Do While CurFile <> vbNullString
    Dim OrigWB As Workbook
    Set OrigWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=DirLoc & CurFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    For Each ws In OrigWB.Sheets
        ws.Select
        ws.Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next

    OrigWB.Close Savechanges:=False
    CurFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DestWB.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set DestWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any idea of what is going on? I'd appreciate any help!
Tks!

Comment: It seems with Excel 2010, directly copying worksheets always corrupts images contained on the sheet. There are workarounds to this (copying the worksheet then deleting objects in the new sheet and then copying and pasting the images from the old sheet directly), but I have not seen any direct solutions. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617122/inserted-image-fails-to-display-when-sheet-is-copied-to-another-workbook-in-exce) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551700/excel-vba-code-to-move-worksheets-with-image-add-screen-updating-and-it-errors) are similar.

Answer (score 0):

just found a workaround that helped!

I just added "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" before closing the source workbook, it takes longer to merge all worsheets, but at least the images are displayed correctly!

Here follows the new code:

```
Sub MergePlans()
Dim CurFile As String, DirLoc As String
Dim DestWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Object

DirLoc = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Merge\" 
CurFile = Dir(DirLoc & "*.xlsx")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set DestWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet)

Do While CurFile <> vbNullString
    Dim OrigWB As Workbook
    Set OrigWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=DirLoc & CurFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    For Each ws In OrigWB.Sheets
        ws.Select
        ws.Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(DestWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next
    **Application.ScreenUpdating = True**
    OrigWB.Close Savechanges:=False
    CurFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DestWB.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set DestWB = Nothing


End Sub
```

Found this workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551700/excel-vba-code-to-move-worksheets-with-image-add-screen-updating-and-it-errors) - Option 1!

Tks Dan!